# node express and angular post action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

**Introduction**

I have a angular post, posting to my node express back-end that sends data to a API, I wish to send the user to a different angular page if post is successful or show error message if incorrect.

I was thinking If successful post a variable to my angular that I can use in my scope to ng-hide/show or load a new page if variable present.

But maybe there is a better way of doing this any idea ?

**My angular post**

```
FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.LoginForm = function () {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.formData.LoginEmail
        };

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/test',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.formData = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.formData = status;
    });
}
});
```

**My node express post to A API**

This post uses the email send from my angular and post it to the third part API, I know wish for a action to happen

- Either post to my front on pass so that I can use the variable in angular scope to hide or show a new page
- better solution is that I can load the new angular page with my node on pass

```js
{
            var headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            };
// Configure the request
            var api = result[1].data_api;
            var login_email = result[0].data_login_email;
            var options = {
                url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                form: {
                    'email': login_email,
                    'user_key': userkey,
                    'api_key': api
                },
                json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
            };

// Start the request
            rp(options)
                .then(function (parsedBody) {
                    console.error(login_email, "Is a user, login pass!");
                    // $scope.FormLogin = true;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.error("fail no such user");
                });
            console.error("Third done");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to send the response code from the API to tell Angular if the request was successful or not.

If you're using express you can do:

```
if (everythingOk) {
  res.status(200).send(successData)
} else {
  res.status(400).send()
}
```

and in your angular request:

```
        rp(options)
                .then(function (parsedBody) {
                    if(parsedBody.statusCode == 200) {
                      console.error(login_email, "Is a user, login pass!");
                    } else {
                      console.error("fail no such user"); 
                      // $scope.FormLogin = true;
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.error("unknown error");
                });
            console.error("Third done");
```

Comment: nice, just got back from lunch, ill try and implement this and let you know. thanks